# Assembly frame pointer and stack pointer

Tags: assembly

I am beginner in assembly. I came across stack and frame pointers and i have the following questions. For a program composed of many function it is there only a stack for all program or stacks for each functions? The stack pointer is a global one(i mean that if it exits from a function this pointer moves in the stack during cleaning the stack of the function called, in the caller function it will be on the position from where it moved in the called function)? The base pointer is unique to every function?

Comment: You can take a guess and test it with a debugger. Also, I'm sure there are plenty of questions like this on SO. Anyway: stack is global per thread. Base pointer (frame pointer?) is can be unique per invocation.

Comment: The stack pointer register is global per CPU core, but OS will adjust it's value per-thread during context switching (allowing for multitasking). The base pointer is what? From your question it's not completely clear, whether you talk about registers in CPU (and what CPU), or on higher C-like abstraction level. On x86 the registers are global per CPU core (ie. super global from programmer's point of view). Whether some function stores into `rbp` value pointing to it's local stack space (thus using it as "base pointer"), or if it's used globally, or not used, depends on the programmer/compiler.